# Translate DataSet to DataContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-3.5

How can I translate a ADO.NET DataSet to System.Data.Linq.DataContext.

DataContext object requires a IDbConnection to a database. Whereas I construct my DataSet form DataTables programmtically.

How Can I achieve this in .NET 3.5.

Comment: Why do you "construct a DataSet form DataTables programmtically?" Linq-to-SQL or linq-to-EF can do that and then you won't have to bother with the conversion problem. IMO, no need for DataSet unless you need to do a bulk insert, which linq isn't good at.

Comment: A `DataSet` and a `DataContext` are two very different things. I'm not sure if I understand your question. From what background are you asking this?

Comment: @GertArnold. DataContext is EF way of representing database as in- memory objects whereas DataSet is old ADO.NET way of doing such. How can I initialize the DataContext supplying DataSet as argument instead of supplying a constant database connection. Basically I want to convert my DataSet to LINQ Entities.

Comment: Well, you can mock a DbContext (DataContext is linq to sql) in a way that its DbSets are populated from data in memory. You could use datasets for that, but I doubt if you will benefit from that. A DataRecord does not contain an instance of some type, basically it's just an object array, whereas a `DbSet` should return typed data. Is that your purpose, mocking for e.g. unit tests?